# Request random row in a query with LEFT JOIN

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables for a quiz: "questions" and "answers". Every question has 4 answers. I wanna request 50 random question. I try this but it returned less than 50 question.

(I need all fields of all 50 questions and 200 answers).

```
SELECT Q.*, A.* FROM questions Q
LEFT JOIN answers A ON Q.pid = A.pid
WHERE Q.pid >= RAND() * (SELECT MAX(pid) FROM questions)
AND  Q.lid IN $array
GROUP BY Q.pid
LIMIT 50
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
 SELECT y.* 
   FROM 
      ( SELECT * 
          FROM questions 
         ORDER 
            BY RAND() LIMIT 2
      ) x 
   JOIN answers y 
     ON y.question_id = x.question_id 
  ORDER  
     BY x.question_id;
```

Comment: I read in this web that RAND() is slow, that it's better WHERE id >= RAND() * (SELECT MAX(id) FROM table). Is necessary in this case?